# I am triying to do junit testing of a producer template

Tags: jbossfuse

I am trying to do `junit` testing of a processor.
The issue I'm facing happens around producer template which has been used in the method.
The processor uses the `producer template` which is sending the return of a method call to an endpoint(this is where my junit is failing...

Does anyone know how to get trough the producer template?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a processor in a junit test, then you need to supply a mocked exchange. You can use any mocking framework for it. You'll then be able to catch the processors calls to the exchange object.

You can also consider using a POJO instead of a processor and have Camel inject the required data. That might ease the unit testing part because you won't have a dependency on any Camel API. See: http://camel.apache.org/bean.html